# request failed with server response DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Required Information**

- Mode (Sandbox):
- PayPal Android SDK Version ( paypal-android-sdk:2.14.4)
- Android Version and Device (Samsung J2)
- PayPal-Debug-ID(s) ( e0dd5a1e352af [sandbox, 2.14.4;release] )

**Issue Description**

- while calling paypal sandbox i am facing this error .. i tried to
  find way to regenerate or reset request id but there is no method to
  reset it . please guide what to do . here is error log
- request failed with server
  response:{"name":"DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","message":"PayPal-Request-Id
  header was already
  used.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","debug_id":"e0dd5a1e352af"}
- DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved .. it was due to credit/debitcard paypment not possible in india via paypal mobile sdk . also indian paypal acc to india paypal acc transfer not possible via paypal .. may be paypal should improve error messages.